# Can I reuse a WebDriverWait object?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a page object which interacts with few elements on the DOM. If I create a `WebDriverWait` object on my page object initialization as an instance member, can I use it for all of the waits?

Or if I wanna wait for two separate element, it's better to have two `WebDriverWait`s?

I'm experiencing some weird `TimeoutException`s and I wonder it might be that. Like:

```
class MyPage(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    def get_search_box(self):
        return self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located('srch'))

    def get_search_btn(self):
        return self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located('btn'))
```

versus:

```
    def get_search_btn(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        return wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located('btn'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is a function which you can reuse as required. Take a look at the following function for example:

```
def wait_for_element_to_be_visible(self, *locator):
    """Wait for an element to become visible"""
    self.selenium.implicitly_wait(0)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.selenium, self.timeout).until(
            lambda s: self._selenium_root.find_element(*locator).is_displayed())
    except TimeoutException:
        Assert.fail(TimeoutException)
    finally:
        self.selenium.implicitly_wait(self.testsetup.default_implicit_wait)
```

Comment: Yes. I can use a function to create a Wait object for me but wanted to know if it has side effect if I don't.

Comment: There is a difference in using implicit and explicit waits in selenium. Using a implicit wait is advised if you want to allow your app to load completely by polling the DOM for a certain amount of time and as soon as the element is found, webdriver moves on to the next step. Read the documentation here on waits for more info - `http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp`

Comment: I didn't read ur updated question. Your first example looks fine where you are reusing the same instance. There is no need to create new instances every time.